# How to clean up amplify async Auth function in a react useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, async-await, react-hooks, aws-amplify

I am trying to use the Private router composition of react-router to authenticate users that land on the protected route. AWS amplify auth is the chosen service to provide authentication. I have successfully managed to sign up and sign in users. My current problem is being able to check the current user session as the user lands on the *protected route*. I am able to logout the current user session in the useEffect hook, however, setting the **authenticated** state to **true** after verifying a session exists seems to cause the problem. I keep getting an error in the console that keeps emphasizing a memory leak due to not canceling the async request made in the hook.

So my question now is, How do I cancel an AWS amplify auth async function request in the **useEffect** hook?

*console error*

```
Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

*private-route.js*

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import {Route,Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'
import {checkCurrentSession} from '../shared/auth-services'


const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {

const [authenticated,setAuthenticated]=useState(false);

useEffect( () => {
   async function check(){
       try{
          const response= await checkCurrentSession()
          console.log(response)
          setAuthenticated(true)
       }catch(err){
           console.log(err)
       }
   }
   check();
}, [])


return(
<Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
  authenticated? <Component {...props} />
    : <Redirect to='/user-login' />
)} />
 )}

export default PrivateRoute
```

*auth-services.js*

```
const checkCurrentSession=async()=>{
    return await Auth.currentSession()
    }
```

Comment: Hey Sunil thanks a lot for your feedback. I will surely give this a go again. I guess, kind of the main issue here is that the auth service is exposing a high level abstract of axios which quite frankly, makes it hard to pass data as second args to it.

Comment: After some research, I came to the knowledge that what I might be experiencing is known as the race conditions. I am still looking into it as of yet and will be sure to update the question on my findings.

Comment: Try this in your code [works for both reactjs and native] to avoid memory leakage with using axios though and update your feedback, good luck.